# Масштабирование письма без адаптива

Tags: html, css, email

Первый раз решил сверстать письмо.‍♂️ Потратил уже несколько часов, но не нашел решение одной проблемы. ‍♂️

Сверстал письмо: табличная верстка, inline стили все как надо. Проверяю верстку на Mail.ru, Yandex, Gmail. На ПК все хорошо, а на мобильных приложениях Yandex и Gmail письмо не масштабируется (не уменьшает) письмо чтобы видно было все. Mail.ru это делает как надо. Прикрепляю скрины.

1. Mail.ru - https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoaAV.jpg (то что нужно)
2. Yandex - https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzcpS.jpg (обрезает и не уменьшает)
3. Gmail - https://i.stack.imgur.com/KndBv.jpg (обрезает и не уменьшает)

Верстка на Github - https://github.com/hattamsoyunov/fulex

Задача состоит в том чтобы письмо было не адаптивным а фиксированным на 600px и на мобильной уменьшался масштаб.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Ну так у вас в коде прописано `width=device-width` — естественно почтовые клиенты ведут себя ровно как прописано и делают ширину меньше чем 600px. В данном случае Mail.ru ведёт себя неправильно.

Comment: @andreymal спасибо за ответ.  Правильно, но я уже пробовал куча вариантов и `width=600` пробовал, все равно тоже самое.